# How can I edit Yaws config file on Windows?

Tags: windows, web-server, configuration, file-permissions, yaws

I have installed [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) webserver on my Windows Vista machine. Now I want to edit `yaws.conf` so that the server listen to another port instead of the default 8080.

But when I'm editing the file in a text editor, I can not save the file, because it says that another application is using the file. But I haven't started Yaws yet and I am logged in as an administrator.

I am using the latest version of Yaws, 1.88.

Any suggestions on how I can edit and save `yaws.conf`?

With Notepad++ I get this message, when trying to save:

> Please check whether if this is opened in another program

And if I edit the file in Notepad I get this message (translated from swedish):

> The file *[path]* could not be created. Check that the file path and name is correct.

Comment: You should get a different error message, but just to be sure, are you sure the file isn't read-only?

Comment: @Cocowalla: It looks like it's not read-only or write-protected if I look at the file properties.

Comment: Are there any Swedish characters in the path?

Comment: @Cocowalla: No the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yaws-1.88\yaws.conf`

Comment: And there is no other process that has a lock on the file: http://superuser.com/questions/166265/how-can-i-see-what-process-has-a-lock-on-a-textfile

Comment: That was going to be my next question :)  What about file permissions - does your account have write access? (although again I would expect a different error message if that was the issue)

Comment: @Cocowalla: Yes, I am logged in as Administrator and I have all file permissions, including write permissions.

Comment: Last questions, then I'm out of idead :)  Is the path very long (may be an issue if it's too long)? Have you tried disabling any antivirus or HIDS software before attempting to save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking you lots of questions, I only just realised that you are using Vista - so I think I may finally have a solution.

If you want to save anything to C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86) in Vista or 7, you must run the application with escalated privileges.

Notepad++ should really be showing you a UAC prompt when you try to save to this area, ut does not yet: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2936528&group_id=95717&atid=612382

I believe that if you start Notepad++ (or notepad, or whatever in escalated mode first, and then open and save the file it should work. If you're unsure how to do this, see [here](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/10/22/how-to-run-as-administrator-in-vista-command-line/) (it's note specific to Notepad++, but you want to use the same steps).